# WebGL (Three.js) Skinning Animation Basic Concept

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I came across many demos regarding skinning in Three.js however I cannot understand that does the model that we import, itself should be animating one like, it is already made animating in modeling software and you just import the dummy model and manipulate it ?

If you look at this exmaple: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_morphnormals.html

Does the model here flamingo.js, already made animating and then exported to js format and  the javascript is just playing through the frames?

Please can any one elaborate me the concept here, i am brand new to all this 3D world and WebGl stuffs I just can't figure out how can I animate any model that is imported in js format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you want your model animated before exporting. There is not really a wrong or a right way about doing this.

Probably the easiest way is through [Morph Target Animation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morph_target_animation). The other method is called skinning, an example of which you can find [here](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_skinning.html).

Most of the 3-D software supports exporting for both formats. If you are not sure that your model is properly exported just check the [three js examples](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/).

For instance here is what a morphs animated model looks like: [animated horse](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/models/animated/horse.js).

[In my personal example](http://slytael.github.io/memories/) I've animated the model through pure javascript rotation and move effects.

Comment: Thank you for the answer sir. It was verg helpful. One more question, i have a bird model now if i have to flap its wings what should i consider? I made a simple bird model with blender

Comment: your example is really amazing can you share code of that?? what i was hoping to achieve is something like it.. instead of the robot there is bird and which is flapping its wings.

Comment: See the [following tutorial](http://www.kadrmasconcepts.com/blog/2012/01/24/from-blender-to-threefab-exporting-three-js-morph-animations/)